How to get value from svelte form component
I am using shadcn-svelte and it's form component. And I wanted to understand, how can I get the value entered by user on the server side. In the example below, I am trying to get the value note. As far as I can tell, I don't think I am doing anything wrong, (I followed this example), and yet when I do console.log in +page.server.ts i get an empty value for note.
My component:
<script lang="ts">
    import { Carta, MarkdownEditor } from 'carta-md';
    import { code } from '@cartamd/plugin-code';
    import 'carta-md/default.css';
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';

    import '$lib/styles/github.scss';
    import { formSchema } from './schema';
    import { superForm } from 'sveltekit-superforms';
    import SuperDebug from 'sveltekit-superforms';
    import { zodClient } from 'sveltekit-superforms/adapters';
    import * as Form from '$lib/components/ui/form/index';
    import type { PageData } from '../$types';

    export let data: PageData;
    const form = superForm(data.form, { validators: zodClient(formSchema) });
    const { form: formData, enhance } = form;

    // TODO: the editor doesn't change it's background color when changed to light mode
    const carta = new Carta({
        sanitizer: false,
        extensions: [code()]
    });
</script>

<div class="flex w-3/4 flex-col">
    <form method="POST" use:enhance>
        <Form.Field {form} name="note">
            <Form.Control>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-end space-y-4">
                    <MarkdownEditor
                        bind:value={$formData.note}
                        {carta}
                        mode="tabs"
                        theme="github"
                        placeholder="Enter your note"
                    />
                </div>
            </Form.Control>
            <Form.FieldErrors />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Button variant="default" type="submit">Save</Form.Button>
        {#if browser}
            <SuperDebug data={$formData} />
        {/if}
    </form>
</div>

MarkdownEditor is a ready made component, downloaded from here
My +page.server.ts is as follows:
import type { Actions } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
import { superValidate } from 'sveltekit-superforms';
import { formSchema } from './schema';
import { zod } from 'sveltekit-superforms/adapters';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
    return {
        form: await superValidate(zod(formSchema))
    };
};

export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const form = await superValidate(request, zod(formSchema));
        console.log(form);
    }
};

And the zod schema is as follows:
import { z } from 'zod';

export const formSchema = z.object({
    note: z.string().min(2, 'Too short! The note must have atleast 20 characters')

export type FormSchema = typeof formSchema;


First thing I am noticing is that in the linked documentation the superValidate() funciton is given the event not the request as in your code. (async (event) => .. vs async ({ request }) => ..)

I tried with event as well, but that also didn't work. However, if I add an input element in the same div as MarkdownEditor I am able to get the value. I.e. if I add the following: <input type="hidden" name="note" value={$formData.note} />, i get the value. However, I am not sure, if this is the right way to do this

Only form inputs with a name are submitted and you do not set one on the editor.
This can probably be rectified via the textarea property:
<MarkdownEditor
    bind:value={$formData.note}
    {carta}
    mode="tabs"
    theme="github"
    placeholder="Enter your note"
    textarea={{ name: 'note' }}
/>

(The value binding is irrelevant for the submission logic and not necessary, unless you need the currently being edited value for some dynamic logic.)
